# How to let argparse check mutually exclusive groups of arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have a test code as follows, that shall take EITHER the positional argument `file` OR all the optional arguments `time`, `expression` and `name`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-t","--time")
parser.add_argument("-x","--expression")
parser.add_argument("-n","--name")
parser.add_argument("file")

print parser.parse_args()
```

The following combination should work

```
test.py filename
test.py -t 5 -x foo -n test
```

but NOT these:

```
test.py filename -t 5 # should raise error because the positional and the optional -t argument cannot be used together
test.py -t 5 -x foo # should raise an error because all three of the optional arguments are required
```

Any simple solution to that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you have specified that file is positional which will make it required. You will probably need to convert it to a optional argument.

Here is a simple way to check that the correct arguments have been provided:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-t","--time")
parser.add_argument("-x","--expression")
parser.add_argument("-n","--name")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file")

args = parser.parse_args()

has_file = args.file is not None
has_txn = None not in frozenset([args.time, args.expression, args.name])
assert (has_file ^ has_txn), "File or time, expression and name must be provided"
```

Comment: @Mathan: I came up with a similar solution which performs a manual check on the provided arguments. I would have preferred a (i) argparse standalone solution and (ii) a solution to not specify `--file` when a file is being provided <The latter requirement is solved in my approach>.

Comment: I don't think `argparse` is that sophisticated. It does have a `add_mutually_exclusive_group` function, but that ensures that at most one argument in a set of arguments is provided.

Comment: I feared that this is the case. But I wanted to give this question a change, anyway... Thanks for your approach.

Comment: I had a quick peek at the source code and the way that argument groups/mutually exclusive groups are implemented does not make it easy to create new groups that argparse can support. One would probably need to subclass the `ArgumentParser` class in order to add that functionality.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 asks about adding 'inclusive' groups to `argparse`.  Its example uses a mix of inclusive and exclusive groups, a bit like this problem.  I have suggested adding a generalized testing mechanism, one that would let users add tests like this to the `parse_args`. But the issue needs more input.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following approach useful.

```
import argparse, sys

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    sys.argv += ['-t', 'time', '-x', 'expression', '-n', 'name']
else:
    sys.argv.append('FILE')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_argument_group('Required Group', 'All 3 are required else provide "file" argument.')
group.add_argument("-t","--time", required=True)
group.add_argument("-x","--expression", required=True)
group.add_argument("-n","--name", required=True)
parser.add_argument("file", help='file name')
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Here is some example output..

```
$ ./t.py -t 2 -x "a + b" -n George
['./t.py', '-t', '2', '-x', 'a + b', '-n', 'George']
Namespace(expression='a + b', file='FILE', name='George', time='2')

$ ./t.py FILE
['./t.py', 'FILE']
Namespace(expression='expression', file='FILE', name='name', time='time')

$ ./t.py -h
usage: t.py [-h] -t TIME -x EXPRESSION -n NAME file

positional arguments:
  file                  file name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Required Group:
  All 3 are required else provide "file" argument.

  -t TIME, --time TIME
  -x EXPRESSION, --expression EXPRESSION
  -n NAME, --name NAME
```